# how to insert the column and update them in the same code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Thank you in advance.

i have a table1:

```
Name    ||   Name.val
ABC002  ||   layer1
ABC002  ||   layer2
ABC002  ||   layer3
ABC002  ||   layer4
ABC002  ||   layer5
ABC002  ||   layer6
DEF001  ||   layer7
DEF001  ||   layer8
DEF001  ||   layer9
DEF001  ||   layer10
DEF001  ||   layer11
```

the output table is:

```
Name    ||   Count_name   ||  batch_count
ABC002  ||   06           ||  01
DEF001  ||   05           ||  01
```

The query is:

```
 select Name, count(Name) as Count_name, count(distinct Name) as batch_count
 from table1
 group by Name.
```

these columns are not their in the table but should be added seperately in the query.

i want to know how to add(insert/update) these columns **count_name** and **batch_count** to the table *table1* 
and insert these values into the table.

these columns are not their in the table but should be added seperately in the query.

their can be null values in the *Name* column as well. There can be two different *Names* or only a single one.

Thank you

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: The DBMS is MSSQL 2012

Comment: The output is grouped. How can you insert grouped result into additional column ? Do you have any logic for that ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying achieve, but I have a feeling you might want to look at MERGE statement.

Comment: that is what i want to know. the logic i am using is : the* Name* Values are unique and it should depend on the count of *Name_val* values.

Comment: I am trying to write a dynamic SQL statement and this value is important for me.

Comment: `batch_count` always equals 1 ???

Comment: @TriV : Yes it is

Comment: I think you are looking for a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want by using a simple query, no need to add columns to the table

This will almost solve it:

```
-- Query solution - doesn't work
select  name
        ,[Name.val]
        ,count(*) over (partition by name) Count_name
        ,count(distinct name) over (partition by name) batch_count
from table1
```

But you cant count(distinct) in an analytical function. This query gives the result I think you want:

```
-- Query solution Works
select  name
        ,[Name.val]
        ,count(*) over (partition by name) Count_name
        ,dense_rank() over (partition by Name  order by Name) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by Name order by Name desc) -1  batch_count
from table1
```

Now if you want to add the columns to the table you do:

```
-- Add Columns
alter table table1 add Count_name int;
alter table table1 add batch_count int;
```

To put values in the columns you do:

```
update tab
 set Count_name=b.Count_name
 ,batch_count=b.batch_count
from
table1 tab
inner join
(
select Name, count(Name) as Count_name, count(distinct Name) as batch_count
 from table1
 group by Name) b
 on tab.Name=b.Name
```

As have been mentioned in the comments, the batch_count column will always be 1 - are you sure that is what you want?